# jQuery event delegation for form submit not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I've been trying to wrap my head around this for hours now but could not understand why it is not working. I have a timeline with many posts. The first initial posts are available by a direct PHP output. Any following posts are loaded via ajax / jscroll plugin.

Any post can be liked, or commented. Works fine for the initial posts but not by the later loaded posts. Now I tried a few things:

```
$("form.likeform").submit(function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // code...
}
```

The above only works for the initial posts.

```
$(".likeContainer").on('submit','form', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // code...
}
```

The above only works for the initial posts.

The following also did not work:

```
$('.timeline__posts__container').on('submit','form.likeform', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    // code...
}
```

`div.timeline__posts__container` being the parent container for a single post.

What I tried next was to use a callback function from the jscroll container:

```
$('.timeline__posts__container').jscroll({
    callback: function() {
        initLikeForm();
    }
});
```

`initLikeForm();` then basically uses the first function to submit the like. While this does work for likes, it doesn't work for my comments. But that might be another issue. I am aware of event delegation and was sure that at least the second function would do just fine, I can't find a solution why this second, or even first function is not working.

By "not working" I mean that the actual form is submitted, not the ajax call within the (like) function:

```
event.preventDefault();
showBaseLoader();
var form = $(this);
var target = $(this).attr('id');
var action = form.attr("action"),
    method = form.attr("method"),
    data = form.serialize(),
    postid = form.attr('data-postid');
$.ajax({
    url: action,
    type: method,
    data: ""
}).done(function() {
    hideBaseLoader();
    form.find('button.like').addClass('liked');
    $('.like'+postid+' .nolikes').css('display','table');
    loadLikes(postid);
}).fail(function() {
    hideBaseLoader();
    alert('Unfortunately your like could not be saved.');
});
```

Comment: Your second bit of code `$(".likeContainer")....` looks correct, assuming that your new posts are being loaded inside the `.likeContainer` that was originally loaded when your page loaded. As a quick test, you can move your delegate handler up to the body and then test for your `.on('submit','form', function(event)....`.

Comment: The posts are loaded in a different container "div.timeline__posts". But that container has three forms within (like, comment, delete). I updated by question with a third example I tested.

Comment: @JamesHill Your answer actually helped! I used the very outer container now where the posts are loaded in. Still don't unterstand why the others methods did not work, though. ._.

Comment: Is the `div.timeline__posts` container present at page load, or does it load with the content? For event delegation to work, you need your event to bubble up to a container that was loaded at page load.

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. I added an answer with a bit more explanation to help others with a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For event delegation to work properly, the parent container must have been loaded on page load. This allows jQuery to listen for events that bubble up to the container that you've chosen.

> Event delegation allows us to attach a single event listener, to a
>   parent element, that will fire for all descendants matching a
>   selector, whether those descendants exist now or are added in the
>   future.

You should attach your listener to a high-level element (but as low as you can) that loaded when the page loaded. To test the theory, attach to the body:

```
$("body").on('submit','form', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   // code...
}
```

Ideally, you would do something like this:

```
<div id="divThatLoadsWithPage">
    <!-- AJAX content loaded here -->
</div>

<script>
    $("#divThatLoadsWithPage").on('submit','form', function(event) {
       event.preventDefault();
       // code...
    }
</script>
```

Take a look at the [jQuery Event Delegation docs](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) for more info